# phpexcel exception with upload file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel for upload xls files. when I upload this file

> (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Hz_h5HT4slblFrSlljTDNwWE0/view?usp=sharing), I have error in $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($this->file_path); line

```
public function read() {

    $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
    $cacheSettings = array('memoryCacheSize' => '100MB');
    PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);        

    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($this->file_path);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($this->sheet_number);
    $this->data = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);

    return $this;
}
```

**Exception log:**

```
Undefined offset: 15
 /home/importer/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel5.php:3554
 /home/importer/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel5.php:814
 /home/importer/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php:192
```

How can I fix this error?